# Como testar o tempo de execução de um código no Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, desempenho, visual-studio-2017, c++11

Estou tentando testar o tempo de execução de um código, porém estou sempre obtendo valores incorretos, o primeiro teste vai ser sempre o que tem o pior tempo. E na maioria das vezes o segundo teste é sempre 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_LOOP                100000
#define NUM                     10000.f

auto sse_sqrt( float n )
{
    __m128 reg = _mm_load_ss( &n );
    return _mm_mul_ss( reg, _mm_rsqrt_ss( reg ) ).m128_f32[ 0 ];
}

auto stl_sqrt_timer()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for ( auto i = 0; i < MAX_LOOP; i++ )
    {
        auto v = std::sqrt( NUM );
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    return ( end - start ).count();
}

auto sse_sqrt_timer()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for ( auto i = 0; i < MAX_LOOP; i++ )
    {
        auto v = sse_sqrt( NUM );
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    return ( end - start ).count();
}

int main()
{
    cout << "sse_sqrt: " << sse_sqrt_timer() << "\n";
    cout << "stl_sqrt: " << stl_sqrt_timer() << "\n";

    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Primeira execução:
sse_sqrt: 12461
stl_sqrt: 0

Segunda execução:
sse_sqrt: 2643
stl_sqrt: 378

Invertendo a ordem de testes:

stl_sqrt: 23032
sse_sqrt: 378

stl_sqrt: 2265
sse_sqrt: 0

Estou compilando em Release x86, com otimização /Ox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leve em conta que certas otimizações podem afetar mais no desempenho do que você imagina. Por exemplo, se uma variável é definida, inicializada, modificada e tudo mais porém tudo de forma inútil (porque o seu valor não é realimente utilizado), a existência dela pode ser omitida juntamente com as instruções que computam seu novo valor. Essa é uma das mais violentas causas de bugs em medições de desempenho.

Sendo assim, calcular algo inutilmente pode levar o executável a não ter o cálculo, bem como até um laço pode ser simplificado a ponto de não ocorrer em execução. Sendo assim, para medir corretamente com otimizações você deve fazer um código que leve isso em conta. Por exemplo, acumule o resultado do cálculo de modo que todas as operações tenham relevância na definição do valor de uma variável e depois use essa variável de alguma forma que garanta sua utilidade, como imprimir seu valor (ou fingir que imprimirá, passando como argumento no printf mas não o incluindo na formatação do que será impresso). Como assim? Veja o exemplo a seguir.

```
  int index , sum , chrono ;
  chrono = time(0) ;                                 // Mede ponto de partida.
  for( index=0 ; index<999999 ; index++ ){
      sum += index ;                                 // Executa a instrução que quer medir.
  }
  chrono = time(0)-chrono ;                          // Mede intervalo.
//printf( "Terminou em %d segundos.\n" , chrono ) ;
  printf( "Terminou em %d segundos.\n" , chrono , sum ) ;
```

Outra coisa, leve em conta que programas podem não estar 100% do tempo sendo executado na CPU, dilatando assim o tempo em alguns trechos. Há várias maneiras de contornar isso mas nenhuma é perfeita. Outra coisa que aumenta o tempo medido é a realização de instruções que mantêm o laço (condição, incremento) além do cálculo em si que você quer medir, o que se resolve fazendo uma medição particular dessas instruções excessivas para saber qual é esse tempo adicional. Mais uma coisa, se a primeira medição ainda estiver com resultados estranhos, faça então uma primeira medição fictícia e a descarte.

Alguma dúvida?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta clara, eu testei o seu código e sempre termina em 0 segundos, alguma ideia?

Comment: Na verdade, é só um exemplo para entender o que eu quis dizer naquele contexto. O `time(0)` tem granularidade de um segundo, ou seja, não é relógio/cronômetro de alta resolução. Continue usando `std::chrono` para ter a precisão necessária.